# android aapt problem

Tags: android, ant, aapt

I am using ant packaged my software, I need to lay the resolution of several different packages, such as (240 * 320 480 * 800 640 * 960), I see htc g4 with 240 * 320 separate package of resources file is drawable-ldpi(they are installed at different resolutions in different resolutions resources apk), I need 240 * 320.apk 320 * 480.apk 480 * 800.apk, 240 * 320.apk only contain resources drawable-ldpi, 320 * 480.apk only contain image resource drawable-mdpi .. .. I've looked at aapt parameters, but did not find a way ....

Thanks...

Generating R.java / Manifest.java from the resources...

Comment: I cannot understand the question.

Answer (score 0):

The Android aapt ant task has the 'resourcefilter' parameter e.g.:

```
<aapt executable       = "${aapt}"
      command          = "package"
      .
      .
      resourcefilter   = "ldpi,mdpi">
      <res path="${resource.absolute.dir}" />
</aapt>
```

(you might need to upgrade your Android tools to version 12 - not sure if it's present in earlier versions)